# Install curl without being root

Tags: software-installation, curl, non-root-user

I was trying to install a R package called "devtools", but without success.

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/misc/u32/huang/.R325/lib64/R/library/httr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/misc/u32/huang/.R325/lib64/R/library/devtools’
```

[It turned out that I need to install "Curl" which requires being root to execute the installation command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package)

Is there anyway to work around the problem? Maybe just install curl underway local directory? Tsk!

Comment: Yes, install curl under your ~. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Answer (score 10):

You can install `curl` as non-root using a prefix where you have write permissions.

Download curl sources, untar and cd into the extracted directory. Then

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr
make
make install
```

and add this to you `~/.profile`:

```
PATH="$HOME/usr/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
MANPATH=$HOME/usr/share/man:$MANPATH
export MANPATH
```

Note, after you've setup such `$HOME/usr` in your `~/.profile` once you can easily install most other packages to that prefix too.

Comment: add `--with-ssl` also... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/821186/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl/821993.

Comment: @becko the original question was about being non-root and curl and probably also openssl devel packages are not installed. So using `--with-ssl` would also require to install openssl locally first.

Comment: I know. It's just that missing ssl support was the first issue I had when using this approach.

Comment: @becko ok I will update/reorder my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I cloned from git. I then read the `GIT-INFO`. That instructed me to build the config then make.

```
./buildconf
./configure
make
make test (optional)
make install
```

Comment: That last step would try to install under `/usr/local`, which likely needs root permissions. To install in a user-owned directory, use the `--prefix` option with `configure` (see `./configure --help`).