# How to upgrade vim only in my own directory？

Tags: linux, vim, upgrade

The version of the server in our laboratory is lower. I want to upgrade my `vim`, but I don't want to affect other people's use. My Linux server version is：`Linux version 4.15.0-122-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #124~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP`.

The answers I got online are all directly upgraded under root authority. What I think maybe is

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

`Make install` must be used with root privileges, which is `sudo make instal`l. I have root privileges, but I don't want to influence other people. If I use `sudo make install`, will the vim on the server be overwritten with my upgraded version?

When I use type vi, it shows that vi has been hashed (/usr/bin/vi). How do I make my vi point to the new vim?

Comment: See answers to e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312556/install-curl-without-being-root (use `--prefix` with `configure` and install in your home directory, without `sudo`).

Comment: As an alternative, you could use [Linuxbrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux), which provides many up-to-date packages (including vim) and installs into your home directory.

Comment: Can you just use appimages? Take a peek [here](https://github.com/vim/vim-appimage/releases). Those are run as standalone files, executing without needing to be installed, thus not affecting other users.